# "continue" in cursor.forEach()

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm building an app using meteor.js and MongoDB and I have a question about `cursor.forEach()`.
I want to check some conditions in the beginning of each `forEach` iteration and then skip the element if I don't have to do the operation on it so I can save some time.

Here is my code:

```
// Fetch all objects in SomeElements collection
var elementsCollection = SomeElements.find();
elementsCollection.forEach(function(element){
  if (element.shouldBeProcessed == false){
    // Here I would like to continue to the next element if this one 
    // doesn't have to be processed
  }else{
    // This part should be avoided if not neccessary
    doSomeLengthyOperation();
  }
});
```

I know I could turn cursor to array using `cursor.find().fetch()` and then use regular for-loop to iterate over elements and use continue and break normally but I'm interested if there is something similiar to use in `forEach()`.

Comment: `for(let element of data) {
   if(element.childData == "") {
       continue;
   }
}`
Best solution

Answer (score 752, accepted):

Each iteration of the `forEach()` will call the function that you have supplied. To stop further processing within any given iteration (and continue with the next item) you just have to `return` from the function at the appropriate point:

```
elementsCollection.forEach(function(element){
  if (!element.shouldBeProcessed)
    return; // stop processing this iteration

  // This part will be avoided if not neccessary
  doSomeLengthyOperation();
});
```

Comment: Do you know maybe what could be the "break" then if continue is just "return;".

Comment: I don't use MongoDB so haven't read its documentation, but it's possible that `return false;` would be the equivalent of `break;` (as it is for a jQuery `.each()` loop). Of course whoever implemented MongoDB's `.forEach()` may have had other ideas...

Comment: @Drag0 You can use .some() as a replacement for .forEach(), which enables you to return false to break the loop.

Comment: Good point @Andrew, except that a [MongoDB cursor object](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/#js-query-cursor-methods) is not an array and thus doesn't have a `.some()` method, so it would need to be `elementsCollection.toArray().some()`. (Or it looks like a standard `while` loop using the `.hasNext()` and `.next()` methods could get the same result using `break`. I say "looks like" because I still haven't used MongoDB, but just now I was looking at the doco out of curiosity.)

Comment: @Andrew You can use `some`, just be aware that you are misusing (or creatively using) a function that was intended to tell if any of the elements match the condition. Kind of like when I see people use `map` and ignore the result (they should have used `forEach)`. It's semantics, people will have to look twice to know why you are using `some` when you don't really care about the result

Comment: @Andrew great tip, however it's `return true` which will break the some loop

Answer (score 19):

In my opinion the best approach to achieve this by using the `filter` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as it's meaningless to return in a `forEach` block; for an example on your snippet:

```
// Fetch all objects in SomeElements collection
var elementsCollection = SomeElements.find();
elementsCollection
.filter(function(element) {
  return element.shouldBeProcessed;
})
.forEach(function(element){
  doSomeLengthyOperation();
});
```

This will narrow down your `elementsCollection` and just keep the `filtred` elements that should be processed.

Comment: This would iterate the found elements twice, once in the `filter` and the second in the `forEach` if it a large collection, it will be very inefficient

Comment: You are right, but I don't think it's a big deal as the time complexity of this would be `O(2n)` which can be considered as `O(n)`.

Comment: Considering SO is being used by others, not just the OP, posting a solution just for the purpose of posting it, is creating more harm than good. The answer above does it in one iteration and is the `right` way to do it.

Comment: Note that the OP's collection is not an array, it's a Mongo DB cursor object, which doesn't seem to have a `.filter()` method, so you'd have to call its `.toArray()` method before you could `.filter()`

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution using [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) instead of `forEach`:

```js
let elementsCollection = SomeElements.find();

for (let el of elementsCollection) {

    // continue will exit out of the current 
    // iteration and continue on to the next
    if (!el.shouldBeProcessed){
        continue;
    }

    doSomeLengthyOperation();

});
```

This may be a bit more useful if you need to use asynchronous functions inside your loop which do not work inside `forEach`. For example:

```js
(async fuction(){

for (let el of elementsCollection) {

    if (!el.shouldBeProcessed){
        continue;
    }

    let res;

    try {
        res = await doSomeLengthyAsyncOperation();
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }

});

})()
```

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is putting a `return` statement inside of the `forEach` loop will do the work for you as `@nnnnnn` said,

```
elementsCollection.forEach(function(element){
  if (!element.shouldBeProcessed)
    return; // stop processing this iteration

  // This part will be avoided if not neccessary
  doSomeLengthyOperation();
});
```

but if you want a deep answer to that question then just be with me.

Assuming that you don't know the implementation of `forEach` loop then take a look at the following implementation of `forEach` loop which is exactly the one specified in ECMA-262, 5th edition for `forEach` loop.

**Source** [Array.prototype.forEach() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
if (!Array.prototype['forEach']) {

  Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback, thisArg) {

    if (this == null) { throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined'); }

    var T, k;
    // 1. Let O be the result of calling toObject() passing the
    // |this| value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get() internal
    // method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be toUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If isCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: https://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== "function") { throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function'); }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let
    // T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) { T = thisArg; }

    // 6. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 7. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //    This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty
      //    internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //    This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal
        // method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Call the Call internal method of callback with T as
        // the this value and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
        callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }
    // 8. return undefined
  };
}
```

You really don't need to understand every line of the above code because what we are interested in is the `while` loop,

```
while (k < len) {

      var kValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //    This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty
      //    internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //    This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal
        // method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Call the Call internal method of callback with T as
        // the this value and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
        callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }
```

If you notice then there is a statement `callback.call(T, KValue, K, O)` again we are not interested in the arguments given to the `call()` method here but what we are really interested in is the `callback` binding which is a `function` that you give to your `forEach` loop in javascript. See the `call` method just calls the object (javascript function) it is called on with a `this` value and arguments provided individually.

If you don't understand what call is then take a look at [Function.prototype.Call() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Just think about this if at any point your function that is `callback` in this case *returns* at any point the loop will be updated as usual. The loop doesn't care about if the `callback` function has performed each and every step given to it or not if the control has returned to the loop the loop has to do its job. Every time the loop is updated the `callback` is called with new set of values as you can see there `T, KValue, K, O` are changing every time the loop updates, so if at any point you return from your function i.e., `callback` you are just handing the control to the loop you are called in no matter at what point you return from your function, if you want to skip some operations inside of your function at a given condition then just put the return statement before those statements you want to skip.

That is how you skip a iteration inside of a `forEach` loop.

Comment: Well explained!

Answer (score 3):

Making use of JavaScripts [short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) evaluation. If `el.shouldBeProcessed` returns true, `doSomeLengthyOperation`

```
elementsCollection.forEach( el => 
  el.shouldBeProcessed && doSomeLengthyOperation()
);
```

Answer (score 2):

// There are two options.

//1. Using 'return' statement with if condition

```
 elementsCollection.forEach(function(element){
  if (element.shouldBeProcessed == false){
    return; //use this return statement to skip
  }else{
    // This part should be avoided if not neccessary
    doSomeLengthyOperation();
  }
});
```

//2. If you would like to utilize the key benefit of using functional patterns. filter before applying foreach

```
    elementsCollection.filter(v => v.shouldBeProcessed == true).forEach(v => {
   doSomeLengthyOperation();// all iterations with "shouldBeProcessed ==false" are skipped
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using classic `for` loop and don't want to use `continue`, you can use self-executing function inside it and use `return` in order to imitate `continue` behavior:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (() => {
        if (i > 5) return;
        console.log("no.", i)
    })();
}

console.log("exited for loop")
```

output:

```
[LOG]: "no.",  0 
[LOG]: "no.",  1 
[LOG]: "no.",  2 
[LOG]: "no.",  3 
[LOG]: "no.",  4 
[LOG]: "no.",  5 
[LOG]: "exited for loop"
```

Answer (score -6):

Use **continue** statement instead of return to skip an iteration in JS loops.