# How to skip a loop after checking existence in an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script:

```
var done = {'foo':1};
var mylist = ['foo','bar','qux'];

mylist.forEach(function(val) {
  // This if condition doesn't work
  if (val in done) { continue;}
  console.log(val)
});
```

What it does is to loop through `mylist` and check if any of the member already exist in `done` if so, skip printing it.

But my code gave this error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement(…)
```

The intended result is this:

```
bar
qux
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["continue" in cursor.forEach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452920/continue-in-cursor-foreach)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue` will not work in `forEach` as you can see here ["continue" in cursor.forEach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452920/continue-in-cursor-foreach).
You can use `return` instead of `continue`.

You can use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check if the object has a property.

```js
var done = {
  'foo': 1
};
var mylist = ['foo', 'bar', 'qux'];

mylist.forEach(function(val) {
  // This if condition doesn't work
  if (!done.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
    console.log(val);
    document.write(val + '<br />');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just reverse the logic in the condition:

```js
var done = { foo: 1 },
    mylist = ['foo', 'bar', 'qux'];

mylist.forEach(function (val) {
    if (!(val in done)) {
        document.write(val + '<br>');
    }
});
```

Or use `return` to skip the function flow

```js
var done = { foo: 1 },
    mylist = ['foo', 'bar', 'qux'];

mylist.forEach(function (val) {
    if (val in done) {
        return;
    }
    document.write(val + '<br>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array's [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) if you wish to do it in a more readable manner:

```
var done = {'foo':1};
var mylist = ['foo','bar','qux'];

// Utility function
var has = function(obj, prop) {
  return Object.keys(obj).indexOf(prop) !== -1;
};

// Get missing values
var missingValues = mylist.filter(function(val) {
  return !(has(done, val));
});

// Print each of them
missingValues.forEach(function(val) {
  console.log(val);
});
```

[**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/pimufi/edit?js,console)